# Android layout-land not working as expected

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm having an issue with `layout-land` in *AndroidStudio*.

I have a copy of my `layout` file (same name) with the background changed to see the difference in **\res\layout-land** and my original layout file in **\res\layout**. I'm not using `android:configChanges="orientation`
in my `AndroidManifest.xml` or in my layout files.

I have tried targeting a *Nexus 5* and *Pixel 2 (Oreo 8.0)* in the Android Emulator from Android Studio and tried running it on my physical ZTE ZFive 2 (Marshmallow 6.0.1).

As a last ditch effort I tried moving the original layout file to `\res\layout-port` and removing the `\res\layout` directory to force it to use the `\res\layout-port` and `\res\layout-land` xml files. This resulted in an error when swapping to landscape orientation on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in `onCreate()` of my `MainActivity.java` and it's giving me an error about not having a layout.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kozlowlw.test">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" <!--Changed to fff from ccc-->
    tools:context="com.example.kozlowlw.test.MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_state_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/message_start"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_game_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table_layout"
        android:text="@string/new_game_button_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Folder Layout

**Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: its working good.

Comment: Issue with my installation then?

Comment: don't need to use layout-port

Comment: to get clear just create a new project and create a directory layout-land and copy-past the activity_main.xml from layout to layout-land by just set different color as background. Its will work as you expected.

Comment: That was just for checking if it was able to find layout-land, I've already removed layout-port. Figured if I made the layout explicit and removed the default layout file it would help me see why layout-land was failing (All I found was a Resources$NotFoundException when going to landscape orientation)

Comment: can to add a snapshot of your resource directory in open state?

Comment: Oh wow... So I made a new project and now its working as expected.

Comment: I added a screenshot but just cleaned and rebuilt the project and now my old one is working as well... Guess something was messed up during a build and it never cleared it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html use this support screen

Comment: also use android:ConfigChanges="orientation" and more properties of this.... In Androidmainfest with activity

Comment: Did you tried invalidate caches and restart option. esp if you are using android studio 3.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with resources not being cleared after a failed build. Doing a clean and rebuild on the project (Build -> Clean Project, Build -> Rebuild project) fixed my issues.

Comment: It is strang but worked for me.